# The prompt value returns undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript

First of all, the user gets a prompt message that asks to choose one of the three options: rock, scissors or paper. The thing is after prompt message nothing happens.

I believe the value entered must be received before any of the comparisons start?

Is there something missing from the code so it cannot proceed to the next steps? The code I got from an online tutorial, but I believe the is not working from the beginning.

```
var userChoice = prompt("What would you like to play?"),
computerChoice = Math.random();

if (computerChoice <= 0.34){
 computerChoice = "Rock";
}
else if (computerChoice >= 0.35 && computerChoice <= 0.67){
 computerChoice = "Paper";
}
else {
 computerChoice = "Scissors";
}   
console.log("Computer's choice is " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if (choice1 === choice2){
    return "This result is a tie!";
}
else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
    if (choice2 === "Scissors"){
        return "Rock Wins!";
    }
else {
    return "Paper Wins!";
    }
}
else if (choice1 === "Paper"){
    if (choice2 === "Rock"){
        return "Paper Wins";
    }
    else {
        return "Scissors wins";
    }   
    }
    else if (choice1 === "Scissors"){
      if (choice2 === "Rock"){
        return "Rock WINS";
      }
       else {
        return "Scissors wins";
      }
   }
 };

 console.log(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

Comment: How you are running it in a browser? In a html page?

Comment: YEs. From notepad++ I run it in chrome.

Comment: please add more detail: what do you mean that doesn't work properly?

Comment: You return it but never write it to document

Comment: Time to learn to use browser console and look for errors

Comment: Also, change the title as it is too generic.

Comment: Why you added **angularjs** as a tag? There's nothing about it here.

Comment: It is a game Rock paper scissors. Run this code and write paper rock or scissors. Then have a look at return code. It is supposed to show the result Win or lose or tie.

Comment: @Marin, I guess you are learning JS right now, and you tried running this in a browser, but to display anything in a browser, you will need to accompany it with some basic HTML. I would suggest, take a look in this example http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp and try learning a bit and use it. If you still face issues, feel free to ask here.

Comment: I know HTML and CSS. JS I just started to learn. All the problem is that on the codeacademy website it works, but from notepad++ it is not.

Comment: can someone with enough reputation check whether the question is fixed or not?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct and working properly, you just forgot the important part of showing it.

You aren't writing the result to the actual document. You call the function and it returns properly, but you aren't showing the answer visibly. Try this code:

```js
var userChoice = prompt("What would you like to play?"),
    computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <= 0.34){
    computerChoice = "Rock";
}
else if (computerChoice >= 0.35 && computerChoice <= 0.67){
  computerChoice = "Paper";
}
else {
 computerChoice = "Scissors";
} 
document.write("Computer's choice is " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
 if (choice1 === choice2){
  return "This result is a tie!";
 }
 else if (choice1 === "Rock") {
  if (choice2 === "Scissors"){
   return "Rock Wins!";
  }
  else {
   return "Paper Wins!";
  }
 }
 else if (choice1 === "Paper"){
  if (choice2 === "Rock"){
   return "Paper Wins";
  }
  else {
   return "Scissors wins";
  } 
 }
 else if (choice1 === "Scissors"){
  if (choice2 === "Rock"){
   return "Rock WINS";
  }
     else {
   return "Scissors wins";
  }
 } 
    else {
        return "Invalid input! Type either rock, paper, or scissors!"
    }
};

document.write(", " + compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
```

You were missing the last document.write to write the result to the document. You can format it yourself. I'd also suggest adding another case if the input isn't valid. You could also put the main prompt in a function and call recursion if the input isn't valid.

Comment: It does not work. It says Undefined...

Comment: @Marin It will probably return undefined if you spell it wrong, so I'd add a case if it isn't a valid input

Comment: this is all the code. I will edit it entierly. I will add html as well.

Comment: cheers. It returned undefined because of lowercase letters, which is not good. It is so sensitive this js.  What case can I add?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back. Try having your conditions all in `.toUpperCase()` to ensure non-case sensitivity